# Can i use a customized value in a join clause using squirrel masterminds

Tags: postgresql, go

I am using golang, postgresql and masterminds/squirrel.

I am having two table `customer` with columns `customer_id`, `customer_name`, `country` and table `customer_location` with columns `customer_id`, `region`. There is an external map like the one given below to map country to region:

```
map:= {"belgium":"Europe","india":"Asia","argentina":"america"}
```

Can I use the value from the map above matching the key being the country value from customer table inside a join clause.

Something like this:

```
squirrel.StatementBuilder.PlaceholderFormat(squirrel.Dollar).
        Select(`c.customer_name`).
        From("customer c").
        Join(fmt.Sprintf(`
            customer_location cl ON c.customer_id = cl.customer_id AND cl.region = %v[%s]`,map,"c.country")).
```

Comment: ` %v[%s]` this will not work. Your current query will look somewhat like `cl.region =map[argentina:america belgium:Europe india:Asia][%!s(MISSING)]`. Can you post your desired query?

Comment: Mahesh Actually i am not sure of the query. But my requirement is like i need the corresponding  mapped value of "c.country" from the map to be replaced inside the query.

Comment: Also can use VALUES clause inside squirrel FROM? I hope that can provide a suitable workaround.

Comment: Can you write the expected sql ?

Comment: I believe you don’t have a country that belongs to more than one region. Perhaps you should add a Where clause c.country IN list of countries and ignore the region. Or create several queries, one for each country/region and maybe use UNION